# I am getting an i undefined error in loop

Tags: jquery, html

below I used a for loop to loop through each question:

```
for (var i=0;i<=questions;i++){   
    if ($("[class*=q" + i + "_mark]").length == 1) {
        var bold_marks='<strong>0</strong>';
        var t_marksHtml = t_marks.val();
        $("[class*=q" + i + "_mark]").val(t_marksHtml).attr('readonly', true);
    }                    
}
```

Now what I want to do is create a validation function so that it validates through each question and each elements within each question, but the problem is that I am trying to use the foreach function to loop through each row like so:

```
function validation() {

    var alertValidation = "";
    var _qid = "";
    var _msg = "";
    var marks = parseInt($("[class*=q" + i + "_mark]").text()); 

    _qid = $(".q"+questionno+"_ans_org").text();
    _msg = "You have errors on Question Number: " + _qid + "\n";

$("[class*=q" + i + "_mark]").each(function() {

if (!this.value) {
    alertValidation += "\n\u2022 You have not entered in a value in the Indivdiaul Marks textbox all your Answers\n";
}

if (alertValidation != "") {
    return false; //Stop the each loop 
}
});    

     $(".q"+questionno+"_ans_org").each(function(){


if($("[class*=q" + i + "_mark]").text() < '0')
{

 alertValidation = "Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 \n\n\u2022 You Need To Remove " + Math.abs(marks) +  " Marks";   
}

        else if($("[class*=q" + i + "_mark]").text() > '0')
{

 alertValidation = "Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 \n\n\u2022 You Have " + marks +  " Marks Remaining";   
}

            if (alertValidation != "") {
                return false; //Stop the each loop 
            }

});

    if (alertValidation != "") {
        alert(_msg + alertValidation);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Obviously because I am using the foreach method, the `i` is undefined. Now what my question is that first of all is it better if I use the foreach loop or the for loop for the validation function above and does anyone know how to fix the code above so that the code is working so that I don't get an `i` undefined error?

Below is the html code:

```
<table border='1' id='markstbl'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th class='answermarksth'>Marks per Answer</th>
<th class='totalmarksth'>Total Marks</th>
<th class='noofmarksth'>Marks Remaining</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr class="questiontd">
<td class="answermarkstd">
<input class="individualMarks q1_mark_0"  q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" />
</td>
<td class="totalmarkstd" rowspan="2">6</td>
<td class="noofmarkstd q1_ans_text"  q_group="1" rowspan="2"><strong>5</strong></td>
</tr>

<tr class="questiontd">
    <td class="answertd" name="answers[]">D</td>
<td class="answermarkstd">
<input class="individualMarks q1_mark_0"  q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" />
</td>
</tr>

<tr class="questiontd">
<td class="answermarkstd">
<input class="individualMarks q2_mark_0"  q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" />
</td>
<td class="totalmarkstd" rowspan="1">6</td>
<td class="noofmarkstd q2_ans_text"  q_group="1" rowspan="1"><strong>5</strong></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
$("[class*=q" + i + "_mark]").each(function() {
```

Just use

```
$("[class*='q'").each(function(i) {
```

The `i in the $.each` loop will be the current input class for the iteration..

Follow the same approach for the other loops as well..